# How to use TLSv1.3 with nodejs 10.x

Tags: node.js, ssl, tls1.3

I was trying to make an external api call using https and got the following error.

> Error: Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established
>   at TLSSocket.onConnectEnd (_tls_wrap.js:1092:19)
>   at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:286:20)
>   at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:203:15)
>   at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1129:12)
>   at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
>   code: 'ECONNRESET',

On further investigation I came to know that my api endpoint uses TLSv1.3 and since I am using nodejs 10.x, I need to set 
`tls.DEFAULT_MAX_VERSION = 'TLSv1.3';`

after which it is throwing the following error

> TypeError [ERR_TLS_INVALID_PROTOCOL_VERSION]: "TLSv1.3" is not a valid maximum TLS protocol version
>   at toV (_tls_common.js:49:9)
>   at new SecureContext (_tls_common.js:74:23)
>   at Object.createSecureContext (_tls_common.js:100:13)
>   at Object.connect (_tls_wrap.js:1127:48)
>   at Agent.createConnection (https.js:120:22)
>   at Agent.createSocket (_http_agent.js:227:26)
>   at Agent.addRequest (_http_agent.js:185:10)
>   at new ClientRequest (_http_client.js:249:16)
>   at request (https.js:289:10)
>   at Object.get (https.js:293:15)

Comment: Did you also try the ` --tls-max-v1.3` CLI option?

Comment: Deploying code using AWS Lambda. Can't use command line args.

Comment: *"... nodejs 10.x ..."* - which version exactly? According to the source code openssl 1.1.1 (and thus TLS 1.3 support) was only added with 10.16.0, i.e. any lower version supports at most TLS 1.2.

Comment: '10.16.3' according to https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-runtimes.html

Comment: I did some finding I don't think ,10.16.3 has support for tlsv1.3 as of now.  see source code of  node10.x : https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/v10.x/lib/_tls_common.js